# Third-Party DLL I am not allowed to distribute

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

Say I have a Visual Studio Project that references a libary XYZ.dll. I am not able to distribute that dll but I know that many people have a license for it.

What can I do to connect my project to XYZ.dll on the target computer? To be more precise, I want to do the following things:

1. Reference XYZ.dll in a project in Visual Studio.
2. Distribute a compiled version of the solution/project without XYZ.dll
3. Let the customer, who installs my program, link the program to his copy of XYZ.dll so that the program can use it.

(This may be an easy question, but I was not able to find the answer, maybe due to wrong search terms).

Comment: I think this is off topic for stackoverflow because it doesn't have anything to do with programming, but rather licensing. If I were you I would contact the vendor of the third party dll, include the installation of the third party dll in the setup or include the license for the third party dll in your setup.. still - off topic

Comment: Contact XYZ support. Perhaps their installer registers the XYZ.dll assembly in the GAC, so your software will just work.

Comment: Another option: Setup your installer to fetch the 3rd party library. Assuming it uses the vendor's installer, they'll be shown any licensing agreements, contracts, etc. Once completed, your application proceeds and references the library from the vendor's directory. (This is a similar workflow to installing a .NET application and it fetching the framework first)

Comment: This may not be a programming question, but I am only interested in the technical site of it. I expect the customer to have XYZ.dll on their system and want to install the program so that it connects to that dll (with the help of the customer).

Comment: can you explain "connect to the dll"?

Comment: I am sorry for using non-standard terminology (I am new to the library/dll topic), I just mean I want to reference a dll from a Visual Studio Project, distribute a compiled version of that project without the dll, and let the customer point this compiled version to his copy of the dll so that the original reference works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the XYZ.dll is installed with a third-party product, you may check whether it is registered in GAC.

If so, then you - in your VS project - reference the XYZ.dll pointing to it in GAC and then setting the copy local to false, so that it will not be copied to your program's bin directory and used from there.

It becomes more problematic in case the dll is not in GAC - in such case you would need to ask user for the assebly's location (or read it from registry if you know what product to search for) and then resolve this assembly dynamiccaly using that path with the use of AssemblyResolve event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There is also a way in which you create a "proxy" class in your project that loads the third-party assembly dynamiccaly from the path on the customer's computer, and then create a set of proxy methods that would call loaded third -party assembly using reflection.